# fatal: could not create work tree dir 'SaloonApp.': Invalid argument

Tags: git, github, git-bash

Yes, I have seen similar questions but none have given an absolute definitive solution.
So everything in my machine and Git was working perfectly a while back until suddenly , I cannot pull nor clone anything anymore
[image: From Github On Desktop]

[image: From Gitbash]

[image: From Android Studio]

i have not atttempted to tweak any security setings for fear of ruining it further. Please help

Comment: Do not show pictures of code. Code is text. Copy the text and paste it into the question as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your clone URL has an extra dot before the `.git` portion.  As part of cloning a repository, Git will take the last component of the path, strip off any `.git` portion, and then create the directory.  This happens before any network connection attempt is made.

In your case, that means that Git will try to create the directory `SaloonApp.`.  Unfortunately, Microsoft has decided that Win32 apps should not be able to handle trailing periods in their names, and so Git is not able to create this directory, and the clone fails.  It is unclear to me why this restriction is necessary or useful, but it exists.

Note that your clone would have failed anyway, even on Linux, because the URL isn't correct and there's nothing there, but it would have failed differently and in a more obvious way.  If you fix the clone URL such that it doesn't contain the doubled dot, things should work.

Comment: i appreciate your help sir, it has worked. thanks